# Subquery with NOT IN with MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I would like to create a query with mongodb which would do this thing:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username NOT IN (SELECT LikeTo FROM Like WHERE Username = "John89").
```

i did something like this:

```
[
  '$lookup'=> [
    'from'=> "like",
    'let'=> [ 'username'=> '$username' ],
    'as'=> "leaders",
    'pipeline'=> [
    [
      '$match'=> [
        '$and'=> [
          ['$expr'=> [ '$not'=> ['$in'=> ['$likeTo','$$username']]]],
          ['username'=> "$username" ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

but i got  PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: string.
what did i do wrong? is the query right?

thanks!

Comment: Not related to your question, but I did notice the double "$" in `'$$username'`. That can't be right.

Comment: anyway doesn't work. same error

Answer (score 1):

I would personally split this into 2 queries, but here is how yo achieve this in a single pipeline, we actually want the lookup to match the "bad" users so we can use it to filter, like so:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "likes",
      let: {
        username: "$username"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$likeTo",
                    "$$username"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$username",
                    "John89"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "leaders"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "leaders.0": {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      leaders: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tXLzed1k6sg)

Comment: thanks for your response! i tried to write this: [
   '$lookup'=> [
     'from'=> "like",
     'let'=> [ 'username'=> '$username' ],
     'as'=> "likes",
     'pipeline'=> [
    [
      '$match'=> [
      '$expr'=> [
       '$and'=> [
        [ '$eq'=> [ '$likeTo', '$$username' ] ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
    ]
   ]],
   [
   '$match'=> [
    'likes.likeTo'=> [ '$exists'=> false ]
   ]
   ]                                                                                                                                             is this the same thing?

Comment: Yes, except for the fact that you don't match `John89` as part of the `$lookup`.

Comment: ok thank you! could i ask you last thing? together this i would filter from this query people near some coordinates. something like this: [
     '$geoNear'=> [
    'near'=> [ 'type'=> 'Point', 'coordinates'=> [1.2744485, 1.5845001] ],
    'distanceField'=> 'distance',
    '$maxDistance'=> 10,
     ]
   ]                                   but i don't know how to integrate it in the query that i wrote you

Comment: `$geoNear` has to be the first pipeline stage. i think it would be best to execute it as a following pipeline after you get the initial results.

Comment: could you write the code pls? because i tried to put geoNear at the beginning but it doesn't work. could you write the code pls? thank you!